# How to get saml response from network header? in angular 4

Tags: angular5, saml

[image]
how to get saml response from network header as shown in image?
in angular 4

Comment: it's base64 encoded XML

Comment: yes i agree..but how to i fetch the SAMLResponse encoded xml from headers..

Comment: @Nahomb :  I am looking for same thing, can you help me how did you done this SAML SSO